# Error code P1061 on a Dodge Dart?

Tags: dodge, code

I have an error code P1061 in a 2015 Dodge Dart, 2.4L engine. How do I resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

P1061 is a "Cylinder 1 oil supply solenoid valve stuck shut" code.

- If you've recently had your oil changed check to see that the correct weight oil was used and check to see if a OEM oil filter was used (the oil filter may not be as big an issue as having the correct weight oil, certain Jeep engines, the 3.7? need a filter with some valve or something inside of them for correct oil pressure.)
- Check your engine oil level.

The MultiAir block known as the Variable Valve Actuator Assembly currently isn't serviceable and needs to be replaced as a whole unit. If the car has no obvious performance issues you may want to document the code and clear it. If it comes back there's an obvious issue and should be taken back to the dealer for warranty work.

Answer (score 1):

[This fault](http://www.micro-tronik.com/faultcodes/obdiifaultcode_p1061) indicates a low-voltage on the fuel rail pressure sensor. Check your fuel hoses at the fuel rail for leaks and disconnects.

If everything is on tight with no leaks, measure your fuel pressure with the engine on, make sure you actually have fuel pressure for the sensor to read.

If you have fuel pressure, do an electrical test on the pressure sensor. This involves a multi-meter and [reading the voltages](http://www.diycardoctor.com/fuel_rail_pressure.htm) output by the sensor. You should get 5V from the power pin with the engine on. Then check the data pin with the engine on and off: you should get 0V with the engine off (no fuel pressure) and something closer to 5V with the engine on (normal fuel pressure). The 2nd link I gave you has a generic chart for voltages and fuel pressures, matchup your voltage and your pressure. If they don't match, your sensor is reading incorrectly and needs to be replaced.

Comment: This may be incorrect, I believe the code is for the MultiAir system found on newer Chrysler and Fiat cars.

Comment: Verified through service information that the newer 2.4 engine doesn't use a fuel rail pressure sensor.

Comment: Yeah, the P1xxx codes are manufacturer specific. The website I looked up only says that way down at the bottom and doesn't even say which manufacturer this fuel rail pressure code is for.